# How do I prove that $(X,d)$ is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

> Let $X$ be the set of all binary sequences $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$. Define the metric $d$ on $X$ by
> $$
> d(f,g)=
> \begin{cases}
> 0&f=g\\
> \frac{1}{2^m}&m=\min\{n|f(n)\neq g(n)\}\\
> \end{cases}
> $$
> a) Prove that $(X,d)$ is compact.

> b) Prove that no point in $(X,d)$ is isolated.

My idea: For part a), we need to show that it is sequentially compact.i.e every sequence in $X$ has a convergent subsequence.

Let $g_n$ be any sequence in $X$., then construct a sequence,

$g_1(1),g_2(1),........$, there are infinitely many terms of the sequence either goes to $0$ or $1$.

Similarly,$g_1(2),g_2(2),........$, there are infinitely many terms of the sequence either goes to $0$ or $1$.

Continue this way, there are infinitely many sequence that goes to $1$ or $0$.

Can anyone suggest me , how I move further to construct a subsequence?

Comment: Sequential compactness breaks down for infinite dimensional spaces because the closed unit ball is no longer compact, so the Heine-Borel theorem no longer applies. So you need to use the open cover definition, or something like Arzela-Ascoli for your particular problem. Or maybe your problem has a special structure you can exploit.

Comment: @user762914 Not sure how you got Heine-Borel or why sequential compactness breaks down when it's a metric space.

Comment: Your intuition is right! Notice that any sequence has at least a countable number of $0$s or $1$s so just choose those elements for your subsequence.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ can be represented in an equivalent way as $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}=\{(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} : \quad x_n \in \{ 0,1\}, \forall n\in \mathbb{N} \}$.
Observe that the metric $d$ on $X \equiv \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is actually compatible with the product topology when $\{0,1\}$ is endowed with the discrete topology. In particular, $\{0,1\}$ (with the discrete topology) is compact. By Tychonoff's Theorem, we have that $(X,d)$ is compact.